# VS Code editor does not recognise variable defined in other files in workspace

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

The "main.cpp" can be compiled and run successfully, but the VS Code editor shows lots of annoying squiggles.

In the workspace, I include files: main.cpp, a.h, b.cpp.

In "main.cpp", I have included all library and

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.cpp"
```

In "a.h", I define a variable 'xyz'. However, when I edit "b.cpp", the VS Code editor keeps showing squiggle under the variable 'xyz' and rising up problems "use of undeclared identifier 'xyz'".

How can I configure VS Code to avoid the annoying squiggles in editor?

---

Update:

As suggested in the answer below, including "b.cpp" is not a good way to organise multiple files cpp project.

A step-by-step tutorial on structuring larger project: http://staffwww.fullcoll.edu/aclifton/cs123/lecture-projects-and-files.html.

In brief, the "b.cpp" should include all libraries needed itself, not depending on the libraries defined in "main.cpp". Then create a "b.h" including function names defined in "b.cpp". Finally, include the "b.h" in "main.cpp".

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You should not `#include` ".cpp" files.

Comment: Instead of including the `.cpp` files you need to edit your `tasks.json` file to have VSCode use all of your source files. The documentation tells you how to do that here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: ***How can I configure VS Code to avoid the annoying squiggles and problems in editor?*** Most likely the problem is with your code and not the editor. It's not a good practice to include `.cpp` files.

Comment: @drescherjm  You are right. In my original way, "b.cpp" is included in "main.cpp" because it depends on the library preincluded in "main.cpp". But in this way "b.cpp" can not be compiled and tested separately (even though most time I only compile "main.cpp"). I have found a better way to organise larger projects. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in order to have multiple files in VSCode you have to edit you tasks.json to compile not only your active file, but all the other files along with it.

My Tasks.json's "-g" looks like this:

```
"-g" //remember not to have multiple -g's
"${fileDirname}/**.cpp",
```

The /** means to also compile every other cpp in any other directory in that and so on.
You cannot include a .cpp file in C++. You must compile it along with your other CPP files.